# Drupal: trying to change default for webform form and move the layout of fields

Tags: events, drupal, layout, default

I have been trying to find where I can change the default value for "Per user submission limit" that is under Webform->Form settings in the contents, I have looked all over, but there doesn't seem to be a place that holds the global default that I can change. So right now everytime I try to create an event, I have to manually go in to change it from Unlimited to "Limit each user to 1 submission ever" and the other field is anonymous user is always checked under Submission access... (starting to get really depressed over this)

The other issue I have is that I have no clue how to get the fields to sit side by side, I know how to arrange the order, but can't drupal have fields sit beside each other?

eg: trying to go from this
1
2
3
4
5

to this
1 2
3 4
5

Please cut me some slack, I'm not really a full blown developer, and CMS is right now looking to be more of a pain in the *** then it's worth... any help would be appreciated, any good tutorial would help a lot too

almost forgot, I'm using Drupal 7, using Webform Events for a event site (running on LAMP if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

To get your fields side-by-side, you'll want to use CSS. There are ways you could do it in your template code, but that's more trouble than it's worth, and CSS is the better, easier, more suited tool for your task.

Comment: sorry, haven't been watching in a while, I have found a few threads saying use CSS, but I had assumed they meant the CSS in templates, does this mean I'm suppose to alter the base code for drupal?